Run cron at 11 30 AM alternating days
I want a cron job for NodeJS that runs at 11:30 AM alternating days. I searched but I get solutions only for daily, not any solution for every other day.
ChatGPT suggested


const isAlternateDay = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const day = today.getDate();
  // For example, consider odd days as alternate days
  return day % 2 !== 0;
};

// Schedule the cron job for 11:30 AM every day
cron.schedule('30 11 * * *', () => {
  if (isAlternateDay()) {
    console.log('Running cron job on an alternate day at 11:30 AM');
    // Your task logic here
  }
});



But I want to do this using cron itself; I do not want to add an external condition.

What do you mean by "alternative days"? If that's supposed to mean "alternating", are you okay with odd/even days, or do you specifically mean every 48 hours, regardless of day numbers in the calendar?

(Odd/even day of the year will produce runs on adjacent days only once per year, excluding leap years.)

I want to run cron each 48 hour on 11 30

Regardless, cron itself has no mechanism for this; having the job itself check, and exit early if today is not the day is by far the simplest solution.

I ask Question Bcz I want ans on the particular situation if you can give and then plz submit your answer

Your question says 11 but your comment says 11:30. Your comment will probably be ignored by most visitors; [edit] the question if it's incorrect.

I have update now you can see

The proposed duplicate has answers for a quite similar situation; you are expected to figure out the trivialities of adapting it for your scenario.

To schedule a cron job that runs alternative days at 11:30 AM, you can use the following cron expression:
// Schedule a task to run alternative days at 11:30 AM
cron.schedule('30 11 */2 * *', () => {
  console.log('Running a task alternative days at 11:30 AM');

});

Explanation:

30 specifies the minute (30th minute).
11 specifies the hour (11 AM).
*/2 specifies every 2 days.


No, */2 specifies even days of the month; so it will run every 3 days when a 31-day (or 29-day) month rolls over.
